# Can "to" cover both "in order to" and "in such a manner as to" ?

Tags: to-infinitive

> System 1 controls the device using the data, and system 2 corrects the data as necessary **in order (so as) /in such a manner as** to enable the device to operate more efficiently.

I know there is a difference between "in order (so as) to" and "in such a manner as to", but is sometimes confused whether which is correct for a sentence I created. For example, I don't know which is correct for the above sentence I created. In such a case, do you recommend using "to"?

Comment: Why not omit all the words in bold print?  They add only bulk to the sentence and nothing to the meaning.  Eg: **.....corrects the data as necessary/required to enable the device.....**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are basically saying "correct data makes the system operate more efficiently", it doesn't matter and you can just use *to* without worrying.

If there is more than one way to correct the data, and you want specifically focus on a manner of correction that makes the device more efficient, "in such a manner as" is what you want to say.

If you want to focus on the importance/need/requirement of correct data, i.e. it's true that "this device cannot operate efficiently without correct data", then "in order so as" is what you want to say.